# Mongo shell closes immediately

Tags: mongodb

When I launch the mongo shell it closes immediately. There is no error. It was working fine (yesterday). My MongoDB server is running perfectly, and my application is connecting to it fine. I can't even launch the shell without connecting to a database:

```
C:\mongodb\bin> mongo --verbose
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.7
Fri Mar 27 10:35:38.425 versionArrayTest passed
connecting to: test
Fri Mar 27 10:35:38.472 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
Fri Mar 27 10:35:38.472 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Fri Mar 27 10:35:38.487 connected connection!
bye
Fri Mar 27 10:35:38.487 freeing 1 uncollected class mongo::DBClientCursor objects
Fri Mar 27 10:35:38.487 freeing 1 uncollected class mongo::DBClientWithCommands objects
Fri Mar 27 10:35:38.487 freeing 1 uncollected class mongo::BSONHolder objects
```

Similarly when connecting with no db:

```
C:\mongodb\bin> mongo --nodb --norc --verbose
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.7
Fri Mar 27 10:37:00.513 versionArrayTest passed
bye
```

Any and all thoughts on how to connect gratefully received.

Comment: What do the `mongod` logs say?

Comment: This shouldn't be related to the mongod - the shell can run without being able to connect to an actual MongoDB server. Can you check your `.mongorc.js` file, which should be in your home directory, and the `mongorc.js` file, which should be in `%ProgramData%\MongoDB`? These are js files run at shell startup. You can also try passing `--norc` to the shell to disable the rc files from being run at startup.

Comment: Running with the --nodb flag doesn't connect to a running instance of monogod, so not sure the log is of any relevance.

Comment: I already tried with --norc (second example) and it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

As, mongod service has stopped; you need to go in the **task manager-> Services Tab
-> search for MongoDB
-> Right click and click start.**
You will find mongod shell is working as it was working previously.
I hope this helped!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow! As I pointed out in the question my Mongo Server (mongod) is running and my application connected to it fine, so that wasn't the issue.